# Information package

Tags: single-word-requests

We have compiled an "information package" to be handed to children diagnosed with a specific disorder.

The "information package" is a box filled with relevant brochures, a toy etc.
Would an English native speaker call it an "information package" or something else?

Grateful for your help!
Aesa

Comment: How about "information kit"?

Answer (score 2):

In British English, it's normally an ***information pack.*** However, this normally means a collection of paper, in an envelope or maybe a more fancy folder. It's fairly thin. Here's an image I plucked at random, which even uses the phrase "Information pack":

[image: Information pack]

— [Raf Amato Design](http://rafamatodesign.com/?portfolio=home-information-pack)

Using *package* suggests **something more substantial,** like a parcel. Perhaps it's distributed in a carrier bag or a box. If including your toy makes your collection of material thicker than an envelope, then *package* may well be the right word. Here's another illustration: the [page it's from](http://www.coroflot.com/aliciaingruber/information-package-for-third-culture-kids) shows the sort of material distributed in this box.

[image: Information package]

— [Alicia Ingruber on Coroflot](http://www.coroflot.com/aliciaingruber/information-package-for-third-culture-kids)

Comment: You might be able to re-purpose the term 'care package' which is typically used to describe a package with useful items like toiletries sent to troops overseas.

Answer (score 1):

It's a packet, or an information packet.

> Make sure everyone gets a packet when they register.

[Packet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/packet) (MW, defined for language learners)

> a group of things that have been gathered together for a particular purpose and usually put into a container (such as a folder or a large envelope)

Comment: Could a native English speaker perhaps commment om"information kit"? – Aesa